# Rails controller code not reloading with rack-pow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I'm using `Rails` with `rack-pow` for development.

If I change a model, the changes are there on next reload, chaging a controller does nothing, I have to reload manually via `touch tmp/restart.txt`, which is not a good workflow, because I loose all session data etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this section in the manual](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.5.1):

> If the `tmp/always_restart.txt` file is present in your application's root, Pow will automatically reload the application before each request.
>
> **Note:** `tmp/always_restart.txt` will only reload the application, not its environment scripts. To reload `.powrc`, `.powenv`, or `.rvmrc`, you must touch `tmp/restart.txt` first.

Since your problem doesn't involve any environment scripts, I think the `always_restart.txt` file should work fine for you.

So simply stop your application, then `touch tmp/always_restart.txt`, and then start again and see if it works.